# Como fazer o SELECT do MYSQL "criar" os dias que não tem na tabela

Tags: mysql, select

Estou fazendo uma consulta MYSQL que retorna um relatório de downloads por dia, mas em alguns dias não tem download. Por exemplo:

```
ID|data
1 |2020-05-20
2 |2020-05-21
3 |2020-05-23
```

nesse exempo não teve download no dia 22, então no resultado, teria que trazer dia 22 = 0, tem como fazer isso? e também , trazer em ordem crescente os ultimos 7 dias

Abaixo como está minha consulta:

```
SELECT count(id) AS downloads, DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d/%m/%Y') as dataformat, DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d/%m') as dia
FROM downloads
GROUP BY dataformat
ORDER BY data DESC
LIMIT 7
```

Comment: já vi umas 3 perguntas com a mesma lógica aqui, com datas, dias da semana... se producurar tem uns exemplos disso ;)

Comment: para agrupar, consegui dar um jeito, mas não consegui preencher com 0, os dias que não tem download

Answer (score 0):

A partir do MySql versão 8 é possível com um [*common table expression* (clausula `WITH`) recursivo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive).

Isolei apenas o trecho para popular os dias entre 1 e 30, a partir daí pode fazer o *join* com o restante da consulta.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE dias(dia) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT dia + 1 FROM dias WHERE dia < 30
)
SELECT dia
FROM dias
# left join ...
# continua a consulta
;
```